# AngularJS $HTTP.json

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, twitch

I'm trying to pull the list of current streams from the API and iterate that information with AngularJS. When I put in the JSON data directly in the js file, Angular works fine. However, when using an http request as shown below, I get a blank page. I've searched high and low, but have had trouble applying it to my specific issue. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Http file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
   <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="namesCtrl">
      <ul>
         <li ng-repeat="x in names">
            {{ x.game }}
         </li>
      </ul>
   </div>
<script src="repeat.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Repeat.js

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('namesCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

$http.jsonp("https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams?json_callback=JSON_CALLBACK")
.success(function(response) {$scope.names = response.streams;});

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, using $http.get('url') does work. I was incorrectly thinking the 'data' object was an array and passing "[0]" to it which was incorrect. Below is the code and it works to pull the info and repeat the data as indicated in the markup. Thanks for your help!

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="namesCtrl">

<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="x in data.streams">
    {{ x.game }}
  </li>
</ul>

</div>

<script src="repeat.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('namesCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

$http.get('https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams?').success(
    function(data, status){
        $scope.data = data;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams?json_callback=JSON_CALLBACK` isn't JSONP (it is plain JSON).

You need a server that will make a JSONP response in order to use `$http.jsonp()`.

Comment: I've tried using $http.get(...) and it still doesn't work. I'm thinking that I'm just not passing the correct arguments and selecting the correct objects, but I've tried every combination and I'm at a loss. Thanks!

Comment: What does the Console in your Developer Tools say when you try using `$http.get`?